# Error caused by activator 1.3.0 to sbt projects?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I was working with some SBT project happily, and after I downloaded and used the new version of Typesafe Activator I'm unable to open the SBT project. When I run SBT on the project folder, I get the following error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://${activator.home}/repository
```

is there any connection between Activator and SBT in the sense of the former potentially affecting the later? or I'm missing something?

Thanks.

P.S.: the SBT project I mention, is not an Activator Template, but a simple project I created myself from scratch.

Comment: Activator is provides lots of functionality but as far as sbt is concerned it is just a wrapper over sbt, so downloading or doing anything with activator should not affect any sbt project.... Unless you are invoking Activator. Also, you are using sbt that is embedded in Activator then upgrading activator may change sbt version... and the local sbt repository.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had same problem after run activator (today :)).
Delete "repositories" file in your sbt config dir.
(at linux ~/.sbt/repositories)